# Set home page link

Tags: php, yii

I am creating a jobsite in yii framework.My folder name is jobsite_orginal, I have two modules jobseeker and employee.I have a home page with view folder,includes default main page contain home page link,

i have gave the link name by 'index'.When click on the home link goes to the  index page in `protected->view->site->index` with the url
 `"localhost/yii_new/jobsite_orginal/index.php?r=site/index"`.

Then i click on register link in jobseeker module,after that i click on home page menu,that goes to index page in jobseeker module ie `protected->modules->jobseeker->views->site->index` page.But i want to go index page via `protected->view->site->index`.Anybody help me?

Code-protected->view->defalut->main.php

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Homes', 'url'=>array('index')),
  array('label'=>'Quick Registrations',     'url'=>array('/jobseeker/site/register')),
  array('label'=>'Registrations', 'url'=>array('/jobseeker/site/detailedregister')),
  array('label'=>'Search Jobss', 'url'=>array('/jobseeker/site/search')),
  array('label'=>'Employer Registrations', 'url'=>array('/employee/site/register')),
  array('label'=>'Logins', 'url'=>array('/employee/site/login','id'=>1,'job_id'=>0),  
 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
  array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 
  'url'=>array('/employee/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
        ),
    ));
```

my jobseeker module main page protected->modules->jobseeker->view->layout->main.page

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
 array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/../index')),
 array('label'=>'Quick Registration', 'url'=>array('/site/register')),
 array('label'=>'Registration', 'url'=>array('/site/detailedregister')),
 array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 
'visible'=>Yii::app()->user-  >isGuest),
 array('label'=>'My Profile', 'url'=>array('/site/profile'),
'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
 array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')',
```

'url'=>array('/site/logout'),   'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            ),
        )); ?>

Is there anything you can help? Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: show your code,what have you tried

Comment: i had added the main page code ie protected->view->defalut->main.php

Comment: what is the link in jobseeker module?

Comment: localhost/yii_new/jobsite_orginal/index.php?r=jobseeker/site/register

Comment: why dont you change index url in jobseeker page

Comment: my jobseeker module main page protected->modules->jobseeker->view->layout->main.page is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>'/'),
```

Comment: I had change hame link in the main page ie protected->modules->jobseeker->view->layout->main.page  array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/')), but go to localhost/yii_new/jobsite_orginal/index.php?r=jobseeker/site/index  ,but i want to go localhost/yii_new/jobsite_orginal/index.php?r=site/index